# Why does arrow function as a JavaScript object property does not get reference of this?

Tags: javascript

```js
 var obj = {count: 0}
 obj.increment =  () => { this.count = this.count +1}
 obj.increment()
 console.log(obj.count)// outputs  "error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined"
```

But

```js
   var obj = {count: 0}
   obj.increment =  function() { this.count = this.count +1}
   obj.increment()
   console.log(obj.count) //outputs correct count
```

Why does the arrow function not get reference of this as the object?

Comment: Related: the arrow function subsection of [How does the “this” keyword work?](/a/3127440/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

To put it bluntly: it simply is that way. [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not get a binding to `this`.

They have a few more limitations and differences to “regular” functions.